# Escape a string

Tags: shell, scripting, escaping

I'm writing a shell script and I want to escape a string. Is there any way to convert this:

```
I'm happy.
You're sad.
```

to

```
I\'m happy.\nYou\'re sad.
```

I'm pretty sure there's some combination of `sed`/`awk` that does this....

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain Bash for that (see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
X="I'm happy.
You're sad."
echo "========== BEFORE =========="
echo "${X}"
echo "========== AFTER ==========="
X="${X//\'/\\\'}"
X="${X//$'\n'/\\n}"
echo "${X}"
echo "============================"
```

Will produce output:

```
========== BEFORE ==========
I'm happy. You're sad.
========== AFTER ===========
I\'m happy.\nYou\'re sad.
============================
```

Comment: Do you use bash or other alternative (like for instance "dash" on Ubuntu distros)? Check by running:

#> ls -la /bin/bash

if it's a symlink, you're probably NOT using BASH.

Comment: That was just a sample, which avoided lauching separate processes in a subshell, as most of the proposed solutions show. I have amended the sample code to do what is requested in topic head. Now it does it.

Comment: Now it works for me, too. I'll remove my old comments as they don't add anything but confusion to the current anwser.

Comment: Thanks for your input, mschilli! Don't forget to rate the answer, should you think it's useful!

Comment: As the question mentioned `sed`/`awk` I assume the changes are to be applied to a file/stream. Your solution requires the string to be in a `bash`/environment variable. So I'm not sure if it really does what the OP asked for.

Comment: OK. I can't see a requirement for a file or a stream, in the OP's request, sed/awk are only an OP's idea for a possible solution. The request states "I want to escape a string", and being this referred to Bash, a string is either literal or a variable, to me. Besides, the only reason I have suggested this solution is that - compared to other involving external commands like sed or awk - it does not require running additional processes to achieve the goal. Thanks anyway for your input, which has helped me to improve my answer.

Comment: I just thought I could be improved even more by showing how one could do that on a file/stream using `bash` only woukd improve it even more. ;) +1 anyways for the reasons you pointed out

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sed 's/\\ /\\n/g' | sed 's/\\'/\\\'/g'
```

I probably messed up a few `\` here. Best way is to try it yourself.

Comment: You don't have to run 2 sed commands, you can run multiple substitutions inside one sed invocation.  I think each one is terminated with a ";" character, although if that doesn't work, then just put the 2 lines in a file and use "sed -f <filename>"

Comment: @slacy: sed -e 's/foo/bar/g' -e 's/baz/qux/g'

Answer (score 0):

This works for replacing the `'` with `\'`.

```
echo "I'm happy. You're sad" | sed "s/'/\\\'/g"
```

Are you sure you want to replace the space between "happy." and "You're" with a `\n`?  `\n` is a newline, but your original line doesn't seem to have a new-line there.

Comment: Yeah, he wants the \n, he just messed up his SO markup (Eddie fixed it)

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you're after.  The sequencing of the operations in the `sed` command is quite critical.  Note that this also deals with backslashes (as well as single quotes) in the string (my PS1 prompt is `Osiris JL:`):

```
Osiris JL: cat zzz
xxx="I'm happy.
You're sad."
yyy=$(echo "$xxx" | sed 's/[\'\'']/\\&/g;s/$/\\n/;$s/\\n$//')
echo "$xxx"
echo $xxx
echo "$yyy"
echo $yyy
#eval echo $yyy
#eval echo "$yyy"
Osiris JL: sh zzz
I'm happy.
You're sad.
I'm happy. You're sad.
I\'m happy.\n
You\'re sad.
I\'m happy.\n You\'re sad.
Osiris JL:
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using `awk`:

```sh
$ awk '{$1=$1}1' FS=\' OFS="\\\'" ORS='\\n' <<< "I'm happy.
You're sad."
```

This results in the output

```
I\'m happy.\nYou\'re sad.\n
```

**Explanation:**

I set the Field Separator (`FS`) to `'` (escaping it for the `shell` as `\'`) and the *Output* Field Separator (`OFS`) to `\'` (wrapped in`"..."` to escape the `'` for the `shell` and escaping the `\` twice, once for the `shell` and a second time for `awk`, as `"\\\'"`). Without further options, the Record Separator (`RS`) is the newline character, but I set the *Output* Record Separator (`ORS`) to `\n` (again escaping the `\` for `awk` as `\\n`).

Now the only thing left to tell `awk` to do is to re-calculate each record (by setting `$1` to `$1`, nothing changes, but `awk` thinks the record changed, effectively substituting `FS` by `OFS` und thus every `'` by `\'`) and print each record (this is what the `1` pattern does: `1` is true for all records and since no action was given, the standard action `{print $0}` is performed), effectively substituting `RS` by `ORS` and thus every newline by `\n`.